# How to display numbered pages in a category

Tags: categories, pagination, navigation

How in category.php to output a numbered list of links to pages like:

1 2 3 4 5

when the number of posts in the category exceeds the number of posts to display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to using a plugin like PageNavi(as suggested in another answer), you could also use a wordpress native function

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links

Though the plugin solution seems the easiest to setup

Answer (score 1):

WordPress doesn't output numbered pages by default, but you can use a plugin that does that. WP-PageNavi seems to be the most popular and easiest to setup: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-pagenavi/